# How do I make a like button in Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-4

I need to make a **like button** where the user should only be able to like a post when **logged** in otherwise they will be redirected to the login page **similar to Instagram**.

If the user is logged in they can like the post and the like button will **change colour** and **display the number of likes** for that post next to the button.

Any tips on how to implement it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store value as boolean in Database to check whether 0= normal ,1= Like against your post.

For login you can use session & middleware to authenticate the presence of User.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a look at this course from freeCodeCamp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE

Here you will learn everything you need (they are actually making a instagram clone in the tutorial).

If you dont bother watching the tutorial:
Use a one to many relationship with a pivot table (one post can have many likes). This way you can save the post id and user_id of the like in the DB :)